# What to do without System.out, to print on console?

Tags: java, io

I have been stuck with a problem that was asked recently at an interview. The problem was stated as:

> Suppose you don't have access to System class in Jdk API. You cannot
>   use ECHO also. You are in JRE 5 environment. How will you print
>   anything on the console?

The question really started with -- Why has Java given us the `PrintStream` object `System.out`? And why is it final? Isn't there any other way to print anything on console?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty odd interview question to me. I wonder what they were actually trying to find out about you.

Comment: Pretty sure what they wanted to get at, in a very backwards and circumspect way, is that you should use logging frameworks (log4j, juli etc) instead of sysout.

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't it valid to check if the applicant knows what System.out actually does, assuming the job is related to low-level stuff?

Comment: @eis -Almost everyone knows how what "System.out actually does?", its quite old now,

Comment: @pap - actually, if the aim is to get a message to the END USER, then logging frameworks are not the answer.

Comment: @KDjava hum. so you did know the stuff that System.out does in contrast to just writing into the alternative output stream, the buffering, the unicode conversions etc? I don't think the internals are that common knowledge, or the alternatives.

Comment: @eis - ya I agree with you totally its not that common,I don't know all these stuff.. Sorry

Comment: @eis: None of that is mentioned in the question though - it's all about how you would work round a crippled JRE. How is that useful?

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I think I see your point there. The knowledge required to answer the question is useful, maybe that's just their way of leading an applicant there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could bypass the System object if you want to. System.out does a lot of extra stuff (handling unicode, for instance), so if you really want just the raw output and performance, you actually probably even should bypass it.

```
import java.io.*;

public class PrintOutTest {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new
      FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512);
    out.write("test string");
    out.write('\n');
    out.flush();
  }
}
```

This has been elaborated a bit further in [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0603.html).

Comment: +1; didn't even know about FileDescriptor keeping references to stdout, stderr, stdin...

Comment: Good answer ... but it doesn't help you write to the CONSOLE if standard output has been redirected.

Comment: @StephenC yeah. If the point is to just get a message to console and standard output has been redirected, stderr might be used, assuming that hasn't been. If both have been redirected then I don't think a program should be able to write text to console (disregarding direct video buffers, old-style graphics-in-console etc).

Comment: @eis - but if we remove the artificial JDK 5 / no System restrictions, then there is a solution.

Comment: @StephenC if you refer to System.console().writer(), that does the same thing. It won't help you if *stdout* has been redirected (like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=319PCkUe)). I would think it can only help if System.out has been changed.

Comment: @eis - I think it is platform dependent.  For instance on classic UNIX, a process can use the "/dev/tty" device to open a stream to the application's controlling "terminal" ... irrespective of any stdin/out/err redirection.  And there was also "/dev/console" for the SYSTEM console ... in days when that made sense.  Both devices exist on my Linux box too.

Comment: @StephenC it is platform dependent in the sense that on some platforms System.console() should return null as stdout has been redirected. It is still not a solution in any platform as you cannot use it for writing (in the case that stdout has been redirected).

Comment: I would think that the interviewer deliberately did not say that standard output would be redirected. That would've made the question a lot less meaningful. As far as I can see, the point of the question was to test if the applicant was aware that System is not the only access to console, and it indeed does some extra stuff that you can also live without.

Answer (score 4):

PrintStream is final because it does everything the windows console /can/ do. Also its the same with "Console" being a const class in C#. The classes encapsulate everything the console can do, and it does in one specific way *only*. You can't "make it better" because at one point, it is upto the OS to handle it.

There are plenty of ways to output something on screen:

1. Write your own OutputStream the way @eis did it
2. Use JNI and invoke a method in a native DLL/SO that invokes a native function like `printf()`
3. Use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and call `echo` program
   and the list follows.

+1 to @eis

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **JDK's logger** (java.util.logging.Logger).

This is how you create a logger in your java class.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class .getName());
```

Also You could use log4j for the same purpose.

Comment: I don't think that this is guaranteed to write to the console; e.g. if standard output has been redirected to a file.

Answer (score 2):

The interview question as stated is pretty perverse (i.e. artificial), and solving it involves stepping outside of pure Java.  This is certainly not something that you would consider doing under normal circumstances.

Other answers have given you some semi-solutions ... if you really, really have to do this.  (I say semi-solutions because they mostly don't deal with the case where the application's stdout / stderr streams have been redirected to somewhere other than the console.  And that is the only "real" aspect of this problem ...)

**If you *can* use the System class (on JDK 6) ...** the clean way to print to the console (e.g. if `System.out` has been redirected) is to use `System.console()` method to get a [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) object, and use that to get a `Writer`.

Note however that if the JVM has no associated console, `console()` will return `null`.

---

> The question really started with -- Why has Java given us the PrintStream object System.out ??  And why is it final?? Isn't there any other way to print anything on console.??

The answers are:

1. For convenience.
2. So that random code doesn't accidentally clobber it.  (Or deliberately if you need to worry about untrusted code running in your JVM.)  But trusted code actually *can* change `System.out` by calling `System.setOut(...)`.  This does some behind the scenes magic to safely change the state of the `final` variable.  (I believe that the JIT compiler is aware of this, and treats those 3 `final` variables differently.)
3. Yes.  See above, and (yuck!) the other Answers.

Comment: *Suppose you don't have access to System class in Jdk API* is what the OP has said.

Comment: you have no access to "System" class @StephenC

Comment: Console class is introduced in JDK 6, so we cannot use it I suppose, as we have JDK 5

Comment: @KDjava - clearly, I'm talking about practical solutions here.  If a  development / production shops has painted itself into a corner with an end-of-lifed JVM ... life is painful.

Comment: if "the application's stdout / stderr streams have been redirected to somewhere other than the console", System.console() will not work either, so this answer is wrong. The only situation where this applies is when only System.out/System.err has been redirected.

Answer (score 1):

As documantation says,

> The System class contains several useful class fields and methods. It
>   cannot be instantiated.

So, as you can see, System class is kind of container for different useful functions. All this fields and methods are static, so it's not any reason to extend it.
Java gives us `static PrintStream out` because it's default way to communicate with program - using console.
If you're not agree with me, please, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way today to achieve the question.
I am using org.apache.log4j for this answer. There are many other ways as said by many here. Thanks.

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloByLogger {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloByLogger.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        logger.info("From Logger... Ola!");

    }
}
```