# Java problems w/ printing in new thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have my code setup so that when a long process is happening on the main thread of my Java program, another thread is opened to show a loading animation on the console, but this isn't working and the loading animation just prints all at once after the thread is closed. BUT it works if I use println() instead of print(), then the dots are printed every 200 milliseconds while the thread is running as expected but I need them to be printed on the same line. See code below.

Main thread:

```
Thread animate = new Thread(new ConsoleAnimator(".",200));
animate.start();
//do stuff for a few seconds
animate.interrupt();
```

Secondary thread:

```
public class ConsoleAnimator extends Thread{
    public int animateInterval;
    public String animateString;
    public ConsoleAnimator(String toAnimate, int interval){
        this.animateInterval = interval;
        this.animateString = toAnimate;
        this.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(animateInterval);
                refresh();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    void refresh(){
        System.out.print(animateString);
        System.out.flush();
    }
    public void interrupt(){
        System.out.println();
        super.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.out` is line buffered. There needs to be a newline before it's outputted to console.

If you need it to remain on the same line you could choose to use Use `System.err` that should work for your purposes.

If you rewired stderr to another output like file you could write your own [console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172817/what-to-do-without-system-out-to-print-on-console).

See it in action: https://ideone.com/mlyPdx

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new
  FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512);
out.write("test");
out.flush();
out.write(" > ");
out.flush();
out.write("string");
out.flush();
```

This is the code that runs on my sytem, windows 7 and cmd

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

     Thread animate = new Thread(new ConsoleAnimator(".",200));
     animate.start();
     for(int c =0; c < 20; c++) {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
     }
     animate.interrupt();

    }
}
class ConsoleAnimator extends Thread{
    public int animateInterval;
    public String animateString;
    protected BufferedWriter out;

    public ConsoleAnimator(String toAnimate, int interval) throws IOException {
        this.animateInterval = interval;
        this.animateString = toAnimate;
        this.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            this.out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out), "ASCII"), 512);

    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(animateInterval);
                refresh();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch( Exception e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    void refresh() {
        try {
            this.out.write(animateString);
            this.out.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

        }
    }
    public void interrupt() {
        try {
            this.out.write(System.lineSeparator());
            this.out.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

        }
        super.interrupt();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: System.err has the same problem for me. I thought using flush() I didn't need a new line

Comment: @user2350334 have you tried the custom out writer code? It works on ideone and on my console.

Comment: It has the same problem for me

Comment: @user2350334 what is the console you're printing to? cmd? powershell? bash? something else?

Comment: cmd on windows 10

Comment: @user2350334 I added code that runs on my windows desktop that animates the dots nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use some libs such as [progressbar](https://github.com/ctongfei/progressbar), [java-progressbar](https://github.com/raszi/java-progressbar)?
If you want to know why your code does not work, you can look up the code of these libs.

Comment: I looked at the former, which works in my program, but I can't really see the difference between how it prints to the console and how mine does